# Errors array in ModelState contain exception =null but ErrorMessage is filled, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc C#

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelstate

I'm using a REST API app in .NET 5.

I have this custom action filter

```
public class HttpErrorHandlerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext) 
    { 
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            foreach (var state in actionContext.ModelState)
            {
                if (state.Value.Errors.Count != 0)
                {
                    // .....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function `OnActionExecuting` hit as I send wrong data so it suppose to fail on converting to the response type.

Errors contains element with the error as the follow:

> ErrorMessage: Couldn't convert..
>
> Exception: null

I want the exception to be filled so I could filter on the exception type.

How can I configure this?

Thanks

Comment: Validation errors don't throw exceptions, they generate a ProblemDetails response that gets serialized as a standard RFC7807 problem response. ModelState entries refer to individual elements, while the exception may not be about a single element. Have you checked the `context.Exception` property? All this is explained in [Handle Errors in ASP.NET Core Web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The doc page shows how to handle exceptions, validation errors or customize the error response

Comment: I'm not sure it's related. I'm trying to map binding a.k.s before it run the api call, the link you provided is response after the api run.

Comment: The code you posted runs *after* binding fails. `ModelState` is created *after* binding. The page talks about binding errors and how they generate responses and how to modify those responses

Comment: What are you actually trying to do anyway? Handle the binding failure? Or modify bindings? It would help if you posted the actual DTO and the response you get *without* the filter. If the response is a 400 with a Problem payload, there's no exception. The binder run, validation failed and  `ModelState` was filled with the failures.

Comment: Customize the response, for ex for invalid json return a specific error message, for missing parameter another exception etc btw u r right about the link u provided ill have a look. and i dont have Exception property in ActionExecutingContext.Exception

Comment: The page I linked to shows that is already happening and how to customize the response. Validation errors already result in a standardized JSON response that can be understood by every client.